# How to change color of one element by clicking on another - jquery

Tags: jquery

I've got a multiple choice test on a English/Thai language web site. Each row has a question and 4 answer choices, the layout is essentially a 50X5 matrix.

```
    <div id="question">
        <p class="word_test">1<span class="1 color_up audio" id="b1e01">the </span></p>
        ...
        <p class="word_test">50<span class="50 color_up audio" id="b1e50">if </span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="answers">
        <div id="col_a">
            <p class="word_test">A:<span class="1 color_up audio" id="b1t01">คำนำหน้านาม</span></p>
                ...
            <p class="word_test">A:<span class="50 color_up incorrect">มัน </span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="col_b">
          ...
         </div>
        <div id="col_c">
          ...
        </div>
        <div id="col_d">
            <p class="word_test">D:<span class="1 color_up incorrect">เลอะ </span></p>
                ...
            <p class="word_test">D:<span class="50 color_up incorrect">เป็น อยู่ คือ </span>    </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the user clicks on one of the A,B,C or D choices, I want the question item in that row to change to green (correct) or red (incorrect). My problem is how in any one row to link the clicked target (A,B,C or D) to the requicolor change. I can see that addClass and removeClass would handle the color change but I can't see how to make  the connection between the clicked on answer and the question items. I've numbered the rows in each column so that the corresponding question can be  referenced but I don't know if that is necessay. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show your `jQuery` code?

Comment: `jQuery("div#answers").click(function (evnt) { if(audioIsPlaying !== true) { var elementId = evnt.target.id; var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML; var oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg"; var audioElement = document.createElement("audio"); audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar); audioElement.load(); audioElement.play(); audioIsPlaying = true; audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() { audioIsPlaying = false; }); }; }) //code for incorrect responses similar`

Answer (score 1):

See [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$("#other").click(function() {
  $("#target").css("background", "red");
});
```

Comment: the code needs to pick up the row number, 1, 2 etc and use it to locate the corresponding row in the question div and then color the question item.

Answer (score 0):

HTML & CSS

I think you don't need an anchor to click, because this time the script check the answer as soon as the radio button is triggered.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide { display:none; }
</style>

<div class="questions">
    <p>Q1</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" />Q1 A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" />Q1 B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" />Q1 C</label>
</div>

<div class="questions hide">
    <p>Q2</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" />Q2 A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" />Q2 B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" />Q2 C</label>
</div>

<div class="questions hide">
    <p>Q3</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" />Q3 A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" />Q3 B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" />Q3 C</label>
</div>
```

Javascript using jQuery

```
var answers = {q1: 'a', q2: 'b', q3: 'a'};
/* True Answers: ↑ "a" ,  ↑ "b"  ,  ↑ "a" */
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).parents('div');
    var question = $(this).attr('name');
    var answer = $(this).val();

    alert(answers[question] == answer);

    container.addClass('hide');
    container.next().removeClass('hide');
});
```

Just modify the script as you need. Hope this time is right for you. =))

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made myself clear, the user clicks on the actual words in page and this activates an audio file, see the jquery code posted above. I should have included this before. My problem now is how to change the question item color.